# how to save images presented at pre login in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, images, login-screen, appearance

How do I view the pre-login image on Windows 10 after I have logged in ([Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJ60E.jpg))?

There are many good images which I wanted to save when they were presented on my login screen, but I don't know how to retain them once  I have logged in.

- I read [this article](https://www.groovypost.com/news/prevent-windows-10-recommended-update-installing-windows-7-windows-8/) and tried the steps mentioned in it ([Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtUYr.jpg)
  ).  I was able to copy all files present in

  ```
  %UserProfile%\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.ContentDeliveryManager_cw5n1h2txyewy\LocalStateAssets
  ```

  to a location and renamed as given via command prompt, but the images I get are different than [the ones I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtUYr.jpg)

Let me know if I have made my question clear, as I want to save the images that are presented before I login to my local user account on Windows 10.

Comment: At the worst, use a camera.